# return data after CRUD vertx into handler to use it again

Tags: java, handler, vert.x

```
public static void addMessage(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    System.out.println("Add  Message");
    String message = routingContext.getBodyAsJson().getString("message");
    JsonObject params = new JsonObject();
    params.put("QUERY", Queries.DB_INSERT_MESSAGE);
    params.put("PARAMS", new JsonArray().add(message));
    DB.insert(params, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            ClientCallBack.sendJsonResponce(routingContext, res.result().getJsonArray("rows"));
        } else {
            ClientCallBack.sendErrorResponce(routingContext, res.cause().getMessage());
        }
    });
```

her my  DB.Insert  methode

```
public static void insert (JsonObject reqParams, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler){
    insert(config.getJsonObject(CONS_CONFIG.DATABASE).getString(CONS_CONFIG.DEFAULT_DATABASE), reqParams, handler);
}

public static void insert (String DB_PREFIX, JsonObject reqParams, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler){
    if(CONS_CONFIG.ORACLE.equalsIgnoreCase(DB_PREFIX)){
        oracle.updateWithParams(reqParams, handler);
    }else{
        mysql.updateWithParams(reqParams, handler);
    }
}
```

and  updateWithParams

```
 public void updateWithParams(JsonObject paramsQuery, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> resultHandler) {
    logger.debug("START WITH PARAMS : "+paramsQuery.encode());
    String sql = paramsQuery.getString("QUERY");
    JsonArray params = paramsQuery.getJsonArray("PARAMS");
    getConnection(connection->{
        if (connection.succeeded()) {
            connection.result().updateWithParams(sql, params, query -> {
                if (query.succeeded()) {
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(query.result().toJson()));
                } else {
                    logger.debug(query.cause().getMessage());
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(Msg.UPDATE_WITH_PARAMS_FAIL));
                }
            });
        }else{
            logger.debug(connection.cause().getMessage());
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(Msg.CONNECT_TO_DATA_BASE_FAIL));
        }
            connection.result().close();

    });
}
```

my problem is that even data is registered in database but the handler return null value. is  there any  way  to return  the  result  after  every  CRUD operation ?
res.result().getJsonArray("rows") in my  methode  addMessage return  null.
thanks

Comment: An insert does not return rows, that is why you get no data. If you want to get the inserted data you need to get the generated keys (or use your own provided keys) and select it after.

Comment: @PauloLopes thanks  for  your  response but   even with  delete or  update . it  returns null .can  you  give me how  to use genrated  keys?

Comment: @PauloLopes i  want  to  get  generated  key integer  but  i get  this  `{"keys":["AAASNLAAEAAAAIeAAC"],"updated":1}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulo Lopes suggested, you should use .getKeys() method:

```
mySQLClient.getConnection((res)->{
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            SQLConnection conn = res.result();

        JsonArray params  = new JsonArray().add(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).add("A").add("abcd");
        conn.updateWithParams("insert into user (email, name, password) values (?, ?, ?)", params,
                (r) -> {
                    if (r.succeeded()) {

                        // Your IDs
                        JsonArray keys = r.result().getKeys();

                        // This should work for MySQL
                        //String q = "select * from user where id in (?)";

                        // This should work with Oracle, since Oracle returns ROWID (string), not ID (integer)
                        String q = "select id from user where rowid in (?)";
                        conn.queryWithParams(q, keys, (result) -> {
                            // Return it instead of printing
                            if (result.succeeded()) {
                                System.out.println(result.result().toJson());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        // Handle error
                    }
        });
        }
        else {
            res.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
        // Deal with errors
    });
```

Comment: thanks   for your  response  but  my  problem is  that  when  i  use r.result().getKeys() it  return  String like  this  ["AAASNLAAEAAAAIeAAC"] so  i can't  use this methode result.getKeys().getInteger(0)

Comment: Are you on Oracle, by any chance?

Comment: Oracle returns you ROWID. I edited my answer to reflect OracleDB

Comment: thanks  alot  for  your  help @Alexey  now  iget  keys empty  {"keys":[],"updated":1} i don'  know  if  the probleme  in  oracle  by the way   i'm  using a sequence  to  auto increment id

Comment: thank you  very  much @alexey  your   answer  was  perfect now  i  can  get  my  keys

Comment: Happy to hear. Please mark as correct answer, so others could use it too.